# Check if query result is empty

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, sequel

I am performing a query to a database in `ruby` using `Sequel` ORM. The query is performed by:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE artist = 'John';"
DB.fetch(query)
```

I would like to check whether the result of the query is empty, i.e. if not entry of the DB matches the query conditions.

I could:

```
empty = true
DB.fetch(query) do |row|
      empty = false
end
```

but I would like to know whether there is a direct method to chek whether the query returns no result.

Comment: It would be better to use the Sequel query generator for this, something like: `DB[:albums].where(artist: 'John')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [`empty?` method](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sequel/Sequel/Dataset#empty%3F-instance_method):

```
query = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE artist = 'John';"
empty = DB.fetch(query).empty?
```